# Delete Operation in database table from C# not working

Tags: c#, .net, oracle

I'm using Oracle 10g Express Edition.

Based on values present in a table, a set of radiobuttons and textboxes are dynamically being generated.

What I want is that when the user selects a radiobutton, and clicks on the delete button, the value present in the textfield right in front of the radiobutton is captured in a string variable and this value is then deleted in the table in the database.

This is how I'm generating the radiobuttons and the textboxes:

```
foreach (DataRow dr in dsData.Tables[0].Rows){

    TextBox txt_task = new TextBox();
    txt_task.Enabled = false;
    txt_task.Text = " " + dr[0].ToString();
    txt_task.Width = 300;
    txt_task.ID = "dynamictask" + counter.ToString();

    RadioButton chk_delete = new RadioButton();
    chk_delete.Enabled = true;
    chk_delete.GroupName = "del_grp";
    chk_delete.ID = "dynamicrdio" + counter.ToString();

    dynamic_controls_holder.Controls.Add(chk_delete);
    dynamic_controls_holder.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"));
    dynamic_controls_holder.Controls.Add(txt_task);
    dynamic_controls_holder.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));

    //The inital value of counter was 0.
    counter+=1;
}
```

And this is how I'm trying to execute the Delete operation:

```
for (int counter = 0; counter <= rows_count; counter++){
    string dynamic_rdio_finder = "dynamicrdio" + counter.ToString();
    string dt = "dynamictask" + counter.ToString();
    RadioButton temp_rdio = (RadioButton)dynamic_controls_holder.FindControl(dynamic_rdio_finder);
    if (temp_rdio.Checked){
        TextBox temp_task = (TextBox)dynamic_controls_holder.FindControl(dt);
        temp_task_txt = temp_task.Text;
        break;
    }
}

connection.Open();
OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand("DELETE FROM tbl_mark6_task WHERE description_task=:description_task", connection);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("description_task", temp_task_txt);
rows_count = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
command.Parameters.Clear();

if (rows_count == 1){
    lbl_notification.Text = "Task was deleted successfully.";
}
else if (rows_count != 1){
    lbl_error.Text = "Task was not deleted!";
}
```

And this is not working. I can't seem to find what the problem is.

Comment: "is not working" doesn't give us much to go on. What value is returned, and what are you seeing in the database? (Also, given a condition of `if (rows_count == 1)` there's no need to check that `rows_count != 1` in the `else` clause...)

Comment: The value being returned is 3 (the number of rows in the table right now) at rows_count=command.ExecuteNonQuery(); 

I don't understand why that's happening.

_And yes, all of the values in the table are unique._

Comment: @SinghSiddharth so obviously not all description_task's a unique

Comment: That isn't so. Even if they aren't unique, shouldn't the DELETE operation actually take place in the database?

Why aren't any rows being deleted in the table in the db?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use it in [transaction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oracletransaction.aspx) boundaries and need to explicitly commit it. More information can be found in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3907896/oraclecommand-update-does-not-commit-changes)

Also note that [OracleCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oraclecommand.aspx) is now deprecated. It will removed in next version.

```
OracleTransaction transaction;
command.Transaction = transaction;
....
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
transaction.Commit();
```